# How to use char.TryParse with my menu

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to use my GetChar method to keep displaying the prompt and reading whatever the user typed on the keyboard until Char.TryParse can convert the input to a char But when I use it just repeats the error message invaild input try again over and over again.

Any help would be appreciated

```
//Returns either a 'C', 'R', 'U', 'D', 'L', or 'X' to the caller
    static char GetMenuItem()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        menuItem = IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));

        while (menuItem != 'C'
            && menuItem != 'L' && menuItem != 'X' && menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'U' && menuItem != 'D')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError - Invalid menu item");
            DisplayMenu();
            //menuItem = IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        return menuItem;
    }
```

> Here is my GetChar method

```
public static char GetChar(string prompt)
    {


        char validChar;

        var input = Console.ReadKey();

        while (!Char.TryParse(input.Key.ToString(), out validChar))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry - try again.");

            Console.Write(prompt);
        }

        return validChar;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: `IOConsole.GetChar((Console.ReadLine()));` call look very strange - I'd expect `prompt` to be constant like `"Enter choice"` instead of asking user to enter it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.ReadKey()` returns a [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instance. You can access the `char` from that using the [`KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx) property. No need to call `TryParse`.

Your code doesn't work because `ConsoleKeyInfo.ToString` doesn't return what you expect. According to the docs it:

> Returns the fully qualified type name of this instance.